# Can't launch a program from a different directory via Pexpect

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface, pexpect

I have troubles launching a simple HelloWorld program via Pexpect module.
I have a directory with the HelloWorld binary - hw, expect script - m.py, and a directory with the same script inside.

```
├── hw
├── m.py
├── main.cpp
└── dir
    └── m.py
```

Here is my expect script:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("./hw", cwd = /absolute/path/to/parent/directory")
child.expect("!")
print(child.before)
```

If i run the script from the parent directory, everything works great. However, If I run it from any other directory, like dir here, I get the following error:

```
pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: ./hw.
```

How do I fight this?

I have tried this on Mac OS and Ubuntu. HelloWorld binary works fine, it is set as executable. Python 2.7.6, pexpect 3.3

Comment: I assume `cwd` is set as the working directory of the spawned process but not actually set as the working directory of the calling process. Which means you can't use `./hw` and need to use `/absolute/path/to/parent/directory/hw` in that argument.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not sure If I understand you correctly, but in my case cwd argument points to the directory where the hw is located(the tree depicts this directory) and I called it parent, because I try to launch the script from the dir inside it and it fails.

Comment: @EtanReisner's point is that launching a program with path name `./hw` is guaranteed to fail from any directory other than the one containing `hw`.

Comment: Right. `cwd` doesn't change the current directory it sets the directory for the run process. That doesn't help `./hw` find the binary though if you aren't in the right directory already. In which case you need to either change directories first or use the correct absolute or relative path to the binary from your current location.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you for the explanation, I thought passing cwd was enough. For some weird reason, this code works: 
`self.child = pexpect.spawn("./rtkrcv -o " + config_name, cwd = self.bin_path, echo = False)` 
Even when I launch the script from a different directory

Comment: If that works (and fails to work when you leave `cwd` out) then I was wrong about what `cwd` is doing and something *else* was wrong with the original example.

Comment: @EtanReisner: [the source](https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess/blob/c1f2ff79ba902cfe1cb0b9e19d25a9ac360e06e9/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py#L203) says that the full path for the command is determined *before* the fork (in the parent) and `os.chdir(cwd)` is called *after* the fork (in the child)  i.e., your initial comment is correct.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for checking that. Which means that `./rtkrcv` version can't work the way it was claimed.

Comment: `./rtkrcv` may work as described if there is `rtkrcv` both in the parent's cwd *and* child's cwd: `which(command)` may return a relative path. It looks like a bug in `ptyprocess` (used by `pexpect`): it should pass an absolute path to `execv()`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That doesn't seem to be the case. Maybe I'm missing something, but actually this confuses me and made me ask this question

Comment: @Egor: run a debugger and see what happens in your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run an executable `hw`, either its parent directory should be in `PATH` envvar or you should provide the full path. If the path is relative (not recommended) then it is a path relative to your current working directory regardless of `cwd` value.

If you want to run `hw` from its directory:

```
import os
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

hw = '/absolute/path/to/parent/directory/hw'
child = pexpect.spawn(hw, cwd=os.path.dirname(hw))
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[@jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606355/12167598) answer is pretty clear, just want to add some more,

If you got an executable script (`script.sh`) in the directory `/path/to/parent/dir`

```py
child = pexpect.spawn("./script.sh", cwd="/path/to/parent/dir")  # wont work
```

As with `./` it is trying to execute from the scripts current working directory, if you somehow need that to work then you can add `os.chdir()`, so

```py
os.chdir("/path/to/parent/dir")
child = pexpect.spawn("./script.sh")  # works
```

If you don't need to change the script path all to run the child process, can spawn the pexpect process with,

```py
child = pexpect.spawn("/path/to/parent/dir/script.sh")  # wont works for my script
```

This won't works if there is relative paths mentioned the `script.sh`, cz the `cwd`(current working directory) is the python script's `cwd`. In my case `script.sh` needs resources from the directory it exists,

So in order to execute it,

```py
child = pexpect.spawn("/path/to/parent/dir/script.sh", cwd="/path/to/parent/dir") # works
```

if you don't got the hard coded parent path of `script.sh`, use `os.path.dirname("<absolute path to script.sh>")` as mentioned in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606355/12167598)